# Creating a txt file with contents of some zero in a line by bash script pro

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I know my question is simple. However, since I'm new in bash script pro, I'd appreciated for any answer.

In my program, user should enter a Number in bash script command line as input as follows:

> //bash script command lines for reading (receiving) N, for example N=3//

And, then an txt output file is created with n zero in the front of A(.  For example for N=3, as input, contents of txt output file would be A(0 0 0).
Or, if N=4, output would be A(0 0 0 0). Zero's are seperated from each other by space bar. Which commands should be written into the above blockquote for this purpose.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: You should show us what you've tried so far. What's *bash script pro*? Are you using bash for practical purposes, or are you learning how to work with it? Things like string manipulation are definitely easier in e.g. `perl`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "How many zeros do ya want?"
read N

a=$(echo $(yes 0 | head -n$N))
touch "A($a)"
echo "A($a)" > "A($a)"
```

I think this is what you want?

I'm still not too sure.

Comment: your suggested code worked excellent. However I'd like it be in C source code (text/x-csrc) type. Is it possible by bash script?

Comment: wot? Do you want it in bash or c? What are you asking?

Comment: If you want it in a .c file extension just edit the `touch` line to    `touch "$A($a)".c`   or   `touch "$A($a).c`

Comment: This is good idea. Only my case is to hide file extension. I want to hide .C in file name without changing  c source code type.

Comment: Try adding `mv "$A($a).c" "$A($a)"` after `touch "$A($a)".c`

Comment: I assigned your suggestion. However, By right clicking on the file and properties in Ubuntu, I observed that the type of file is "plain text document (text/plain)" whereas I'd like to be C source code type without existing .c as file name extension.

Comment: In order for it to change you'll need actual c code in the file. If it only contains plain text, it will only be listed as a plain text file.

Comment: Thanks. I will assign your advise.